# Asymmetric VAR Models

Tags: r, time-series, python, vector-autoregression

I know that VARs employ the same number of lags for each variable in the model. However, what if we were dealing with a scenario where each variable in the VAR model has a unique number of lags. Thus, making the VAR model an Asymmetric model.

Are there any packages in either `R` or `Python` that can perform such a model?

Furthermore, is there a big difference in the results between a typical symmetric VAR model compared to an Asymmetric VAR model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the [`restrict`](https://rdrr.io/cran/vars/man/restrict.html) function from the [`vars`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/index.html) package in R. First, you would estimate a high-order unrestricted model and then eliminate the unwanted terms using `restrict`.

The results could be very different between the full model and the restricted one, especially if a lot of terms are eliminated by the restriction.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the guidance here. I'll take a look at that `vars` package.

So if I am understanding correctly, first estimate the unrestricted VAR model and then use the `restrict` method to implement the restrictions. Looks like I'll just need to provide the method with a restriction matrix since I already have in mind which lags I am interested in for each endog variable.

Comment: would it be possible to have an `endog` variables lag be greater than the max lag that the `VARselect` results in? For example, conducting a cross correlation analysis tells us that `y1` and `y2` have the highest correlation at time lag of 22. However, the `VARselect` results in the lowest AIC of 4. Does it make sense to use the cross correlation in such a way?

Comment: @TimothyMcwilliams, `VARselect` only considers unrestricted models, so it will not help you select a good restricted model.

Comment: makes sense. In your experience, is there a best practice methodology for selecting a good restricted model?

Comment: It depends. If there was a universally best practice, we would know about it. But there is no free lunch. @TimothyMcwilliams